# Unable to add data:image/jpeg;base64 to docx document with add_picture

Tags: python, base64, azure-blob-storage, python-docx

I retrieve a base64 image from the azure blob storage and decode it as follows:

```
connection_string = environ.get('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')
container_name = environ.get('AZURE_BLOB_CONTAINER')
        
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, container_name=container_name, blob_name=filename)
blob_data = blob.download_blob().readall()
image = blob_data.decode()
```

The resulting base64 is as follows:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAUFBQUGBQYHBwYJCQgJCQ0MCwsMDRMODw4PDhMdEhUSEhUSHRofGRcZHxouJCAgJC41LSotNUA5OUBRTVFqao4BBQUFBQYFBgcHBgkJCAkJDQwLCwwNEw4PDg8OEx0SFRISFRIdGh8ZFUVm5O4XD0TjiuoV56o4eHOVgYwj+v36Jpr0sQkVKQYfeYT2NIgFpL7eQITe1qDDbGpcY3GE17mgTldOfRxlzTBgt181iNymOAe
(there is more in between ofcourse but I have just an x amount of characters :()
L+w2JR3MDl2vVSqzxQoap0sv91BKVDXvjYiYE1KC+/bywtgt5Et+nYgNINvL+9phKNlUj98yzA3dKfogFCrsXl9cZFIjOiVfk0sWkYXdkWLTMWSF3Ulk2QoW1Qtq3Ldbb0dqgr/ACsFXVbfZs2jIj1dDwh4axZRQobwvMFRxeOjGSRUqRv8W223ZPjLBWm25Y6Yeyd0ygU/Q25tq3X3Z9VuW7NygKgRPyoTLcttt2XbaCzvhy7r7b//2Q==
```

This is where I am a bit stuck. I tried a few things or maybe I just do not understand it well enough. I try to add the image to my document by using

```
word_doc.add_picture(image)
```

This however, results in the error that the 'File name too long'
I also tried using a BytesIO

```
image = io.BytesIO(blob_data)
word_doc.add_picture(image)
```

But that just results in an empty exception as follows:

```
===== Exception =====

[]
==================
```

If there is anyone who can give me a pointer or push in the right direction, I would be really glad.

Comment: according to the linked Q/A you have to decode the Base64 data. Just pay attention to the fact that you have a Data URL and the Base64 data begins after `;base64,`, so you have to cut off everything from the beginning  including the `,`.

Comment: @jps Thank you! It was the remove ;base64 part of the Data url that I was missing from the story. I have it working now :D

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And then you base64 decoded it as suggested in the linked answer? Please click on "yes, it answers my question" if the linked q/a helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by jps in the comments, removing up until the ;base64, part of the data url did the trick before decoding! Case closed